# How do I set an objects property from a query?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to return three values to my front end. My problem is (or at least I think) is that it is returning as a boolean. Here is my code:

```
<?php
  require "../../inc/dbinfo.inc";

  ini_set("log_errors", 1);
  ini_set("error_log", "/tmp/php-error.log");
  error_log( "#################################################     FT-VENDOR-INVOICE-FILLOUT.PHP    #################################################" );

  $num = $_POST['num'];

  $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS sq FROM tblVendorInvoices WHERE VendorPOID1 = ?");
  $sql->bind_param("i",$num);
  $sql->execute();
  $hold = $sql->get_result();
  $obj->sq = $hold->fetch_object();
  $obj->sq = round($obj->sq,2);

  $sql2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT POAmount AS poam FROM tblVendorPOs WHERE VENDORPOID = ?");
  $sql2->bind_param("d",$num);
  $sql2->execute();
  $hold2 = $sql2->get_result();
  $obj->poam = $hold2->fetch_object();
  $obj->poam = round($obj->poam,2);

  $sql3 = $conn->prepare("SELECT SUM(VdrInvoiceAmount) AS itd FROM tblVendorInvoices WHERE VendorPOID1 = ?");
  $sql3->bind_param("d",$num);
  $sql3->execute();
  $hold3 = $sql3->get_result();
  $obj->itd = $hold3->fetch_object();
  $obj->itd = round($obj->itd,2);

  echo json_encode($obj);
  exit();
?>
```

My error log is reporting:

```
[01-Aug-2018 09:15:49 America/Toronto] #################################################     FT-VENDOR-INVOICE-FILLOUT.PHP    #################################################
[01-Aug-2018 09:15:49 America/Toronto] PHP Warning:  Creating default object from empty value in /var/www/html/fetch/ft-vendor-invoice-fillout.php on line 14
[01-Aug-2018 09:15:49 America/Toronto] PHP Notice:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int in /var/www/html/fetch/ft-vendor-invoice-fillout.php on line 15
[01-Aug-2018 09:15:49 America/Toronto] PHP Notice:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int in /var/www/html/fetch/ft-vendor-invoice-fillout.php on line 22
[01-Aug-2018 09:15:49 America/Toronto] PHP Notice:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int in /var/www/html/fetch/ft-vendor-invoice-fillout.php on line 29
```

Current Response: `{"sq":1,"poam":1,"itd":1}`

Desired Response is this exact format but the numbers are wrong. They are queried values so I'm sorry I can't give an exact output. I've tried typecasting some of these lines but to no success. I don't really understand why I'm getting this int conversion error in my log so an explanation of that would be amazing. The first value should always be an in and the second and third should be float.

Also, I couldn't understand most of PHP docs explanations so please don't reference those.

Comment: Assign the required values to an Array and then json_encode to send

Comment: You're fetching an object (`$obj->sq = $hold->fetch_object();`), and then trying to round it (`round($obj->sq,2);`).  That's not going to work.

Comment: You're also not defining `$obj` in the first place, hence the "default object from empty value" warning.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol this is just `$obj = new stdClass();` correct?

Comment: curious as to why you have three separate SQL queries, as it would be more efficient to have one query (and why your error log claims that Toronto is in America).

Comment: @YvonneAburrow *"and why your error log claims that Toronto is in America"* - Because that's how php.net set it up. Toronto/Canada is part of North "America".

Comment: @YvonneAburrow it's not always more efficient to run one query. That depends upon the schema and index setup. Also, that's a [timezone](https://www.zeitverschiebung.net/en/timezone/america--toronto)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have misunderstood what `fetch_object()` does. It returns an object, not a single field. You need to first reference the field, and then assign that to your object.

It also appears that you can combine two of your queries into one, so below is a re-factored code base for you:

```
<?php

require '../../inc/dbinfo.inc';

// Retrieve the POST var:
$num = $_POST['num'];

// Create our blank object:
$obj = new stdClass();

// Combines query 1 and 3:
$sql = $conn->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) AS sq, SUM(VdrInvoiceAmount) AS itd FROM tblVendorInvoices WHERE VendorPOID1 = ?');
$sql->bind_param('i', $num);
$sql->execute();
$hold = $sql->get_result();
$res = $hold->fetch_object();

$obj->sq = round( $res->sq, 2 );
$obj->itd = round( $res->itd, 2 );

$sql2 = $conn->prepare('SELECT POAmount AS poam FROM tblVendorPOs WHERE VENDORPOID = ?');
$sql2->bind_param('d', $num);
$sql2->execute();
$hold = $sql2->get_result();
$res  = $hold->fetch_object();

$obj->pam = round( $res->poam, 2 );

// May also be handy to output JSON headers:
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($obj);
exit();
```

Comment: This worked great. I had to comment out the 'header' line at the bottom though, this gave me a syntax error for some reason. I can't accept the answer for another two mins but this did the trick

Comment: @Jordan it shouldn't have given a syntax error, but may have produced a warning if you already had output (i.e. other warnings or content) sent to the browser.

Comment: It might be the jQuery i'm using to display it to my page because the response is the output im looking for, just highlighted differently.

Comment: @RaymondNijland how do you know the table shares the same field?

Comment: Never mind readed the used column in both query to fast.. After rereading i saw it's using `VendorPOID1` and `VENDORPOID`  almost the same without the 1..